# how to connect the Internet via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, internet, 19.10

Can I connect to the internet using Bluetooth?

Ubuntu 19.10
I do not have a phone or any devices that uses Bluetooth.

Comment: You would need to have a bluetooth enabled device that connected to the internet, which you do not have.